# Java: Delegation Pattern and Protected Methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator, delegation

I have been using delegation pattern to wrap an object created by a factory in a 3rd party library. Recently, the library added a protected method in the base class and my wrapper class doesn't work any longer. Does anyone have a good solution without resorting to reflection?

This is in 3rd party library and in their package,

```
public class Base {
    public void foo();

    protected void bar(); // Newly added
}
```

This is in my own package,

```
public class MyWrapper extends Base {
    private Base delegate;

    public MyWrapper(Base delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void foo() {
        delegate.foo()
    }

    protected void bar() {
        // Don't know what to do
    }
}
```

EDIT: My original post wasn't clear. These 2 classes are in different packages.

To answer the question why I need delegation. This is a typical use-case of Delegation/Wrapper pattern and I can't show it here in a few lines of code. The library exposes Base class but the actual object from their factory is a derived class of Base. The actual class changes depending on configuration. So I don't know what delegate is. Therefore  straight inheritance pattern doesn't work here.

Comment: Well, what is the purpose of that method? Can you just ignore it? I guess not, as you state "doesn't work any longer" ... can you call super.bar()? Just a shot into the blue ... DO you have any whatsoever docu on that new method?

Comment: did you tried to move your wrapper class to a package with the same name/path than the one that the base class has?? it's more a hack than a solution but `protected` methods should be accessible within the same package

Comment: Base class' `foo()` and `bar()` methods look as if `Base` were an interface or an abstract class. Could you please specify your question? In what way would you need reflection? As it is protected, you may not need to override it at all.

Comment: @Fildor he wants to do `delegate.bar()`, not `this.bar()`

Comment: Who is supposed to call `bar`? I assume you won't extend `MyWrapper`, so why do you need `bar` in `MyWrapper` in the first place?

Comment: @Kent, you are right. At second thought, I agree he doesn't need to delegate it at all.

Comment: @Fildor I feel the same.

Comment: Dude, you should be able to use your method as usual. Extending class can use all protected fields and properties of parent class. I just tested your code without any problem.

Comment: I think we miss the Problem. He is *able* to call `delegate.bar()`, yes. But should he? Obviously the implementation that ignores `bar()` "does not work" ... @ZZCoder: We need more info.

Comment: I got his problem. his base class does not have public modifier. Means the class itself is not visible outside package. It has nothing to do with base's protected method. Check out my answer.

Comment: @Fildor Just updated my question with answers to your question.

Comment: OK, so your delegate runtime type is actually a type that extends Base... hmmm ... tricky one.

Answer (score 4):

```
Access Levels
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public      Y          Y        Y         Y
protected   Y          Y        Y         N
no modifier Y          Y        N         N
private     Y          N        N         N
```

`protected` has `package` access too, do you see any specific issue with this:

```
class Base {
        public void foo(){};

        protected void bar(){}; // Newly added
    }

    class MyWrapper  {
        private Base delegate;

        public MyWrapper(Base delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        public void foo() {
            delegate.foo();
        }

        protected void bar() {
            // Don't know what to do
            delegate.bar(); //since its in same package, it can be referenced, do you expect compile time error?
        }
    }
```

Further while using delegator pattern why wrapper class extends `Base` class, I don't see specific need since you already have an instance of `Base`. To me it seems more of an decorator.

Comment: The Base class is in a 3rd party library. My class is in a different package.

Comment: @ZZCoder you can create the same package structure in your own library and then your wrapper class would be in the _same_ package as the `Base` class, it's a kind of a hack and it would be misleading to the client code of your wrapper, but at least it would give you access to that protected method. That's what I meant in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (or shouldn't?) delegate that bar method.

If the library defined a protected method. It doesn't want user (of course in different package) to invoke that method, unless creating subclass of that type. You are trying to break the rule.

If you want to do it, there is way, you create a subtype of `Base`,say `SubBase`,  you create object of `SubBase` instead of `Base`, then pass `subBase` to your wrapper. then you could in your wrapper `bar()` method write `delegate.bar()` In this way, the `SubBase` is actually the delegate, or to say your wrapper is delegating `SubBase` not `Base`

I think you know what I mean, so I just don't type example codes, only this line I guess it is enough:

```
//Wrapper

 private SubBase delegate;
```

You see the wrapper is not necessary any longer if you have `SubBase`. You could even define a `public void pubBar()` in your `SubBase`, and there you call `this.bar()`. in this way all objects of SubBase have access to the protected method (`via pubBar()`), no matter from which package

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that the `Base` class is either an interface or an abstract class. If so, you *must* implement the `bar()` method, for example by using any of the three methods listed below.

Side note, if `Base` is a normal class, you do not have do anything (a call to an instance of `MyWrapper.bar()` will actually result in a call to `Base.bar()`.

---

**Delegate to the parent object**

This is usually a good idea if the `bar()` method is used as a callback in the 3rd party API:

```
@Override
protected void bar() {
    delegate.bar();
}
```

---

**Do nothing**

Just added an empty method to avoid compile errors:

```
@Override
protected void bar() {
    // silently ignored
}
```

---

**Throw an exception**

Violently prevent any usage of the new method:

```
@Override
protected void bar() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
}
```

---

As a side note, a more robust construction is to prefer [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to decouple your implementation from the 3rd party implementation, e.g.

```
public class MyWrapper {    // does not extend Base
    private Base delegate;

    public MyWrapper(Base delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void foo() {
        delegate.foo()
    }

    // does not have to implement bar()
}
```

Comment: So you too are saying that he must not delegate the `bar`-Method, correct? In your example he wouldn't have a choice anyway.

Comment: @Fildor @ZZCoder See my update. Since the `MyWrapper` class inherits from the `Base` it *must* implement the `bar()` method if `Base` is an abstract class or an interface.

Comment: Does it have to extend `Base` ? If not, I'd go for matsev's wrapper that avoids inheritance. If yes, then all your clients do not know abut the new method, right? And I guess you are not putting a reference to it into the 3rd party lib ... so in that case I'd just implement an empty "dummy".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring for injecting in Wrapper the "Base delegate" from another module and for getting the delegate i'm using a pojo factory.

```
<bean id="interfaceDelegate" factory-bean="DelegatePojoFactory"
    factory-method="getMyDelegateInstance">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value>OnLine</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="wrapper" class="path.Wrapper">
      <property name="delegate" ref="interfaceDelegate"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your delegator to be an actual instance of the base class, you can simply remove that relation:

```
public class MyWrapper {
    private Base delegate;

    public MyWrapper(Base delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void foo() {
        delegate.foo()
    }

}
```

Whether that works for you is highly dependent on your other code, and your needs aren't completely clear to me right now.

If the library defines an interface providing the public method which is implemented by the abstract base class, you could sensibly implement that interface without inheriting from the abstract base class, which might also satisfy your needs.